# Как в Adobe After Effects присвоить значение положения через скрипт?

Tags: javascript, actionscript, after-effects

Допустим в параметре opacity я спокойно могу прописать:

```
 transform.opacity = 50;
```

и объект будет полупрозрачным!
А вот с параметром position так уже не получается....
я прописал так:

```
transform.position[0] = 400;
transform.position[1] = 400;
```

Но обьект даже не сдвинулся и высветилась ошибка...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: То что я прописал! но ошибка!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо этого всего

```
transform.position[0] = 400;
transform.position[1] = 400;
```

напишите просто `[400,400]`
Таким образом вы задаете x и y `[x,y]` или `[x,y,z]`

Подробней можно прочитать в [документации](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/edit-expressions.html#link-expressions)

В примере в документации есть строка:

```
 temp = thisComp.layer("Layer 1").transform.position[1]; 
  [temp, temp]
```

Где `transform.position[1]` - это геттер (получаем значение `y` `слоя 1`) `[temp, temp]` - сеттер (задаем значение `x` и `y` данному элементу)